# Why has my enchantress been turning me into a chicken?

Tags: diablo-iii

My follower has the skill that turns enemies into chickens. However,
on rare occasions, it seems to backfire and turn **me** into a chicken.

Is this a bug? If not, is there something I can do to avoid it? It's
quite a dangerous thing to be pecking around nightmare monsters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a bug. Occasionally the Enchantresses ['**Mass Control**'](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/follower/enchantress/skill/mass-control) effect targets you instead of your enemies. One theory I've seen is that it is effected by mobs with the 'Reflect Damage' property and is being reflected to target the player.

It's... highly annoying, but I don't know of any fix at the moment, other than either eating the repair bills, using a different follower, or respeccing her out of the ability. Fortunately, [the alternative](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/follower/enchantress/skill/focused-mind) is pretty useful.

Comment: Useful, but not nearly as interesting. =)